# Maximum sum of differences of adjacent elements in array

Tags: c++, algorithm

For an array of **N** integers, at most **K** will be taken out (without changing the original order of elements). A function *f* calculates the sum of differences between adjacent elements (when thought about, for a given sequence of numbers, the result value of *f* will be *lastNumber - firstNumber*, because all the others in between will get canceled out). The job is to find out the maximum value that *f* can have when an arbitrary choice of *m<=K* numbers get taken out of the array (resulting in a new array).

Since for *f*, only the first and the last element matter, my angle was to cover the cases when these "bounds" shifted, for the given *m*, compare the results and take the greatest value. If I examined the code correctly, the time complexity is **o(n^2)**, but when I sent it over for evaluation, the response was 'Time Limit Exceeded'. Is there a better approach to this problem or did I miss something in my code (I made a few test examples and the outputs were correct, so it's a matter of algorithm, I believe).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N, K;
    int *arr;
    int max;

    cin >> N;

    arr = new int[N];

    //Some input constraints

    if (N < 2 || N > 500000) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Los input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cin >> K;


    if (K < 0 || K > N - 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Los input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < -1000000 || arr[i] > 1000000) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Los input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }   
    }

    //The nested loop which checks boundary differences
    //depending on where the bounds are 

    max = arr[N-1] - arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i <= K; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j <= K - i; j++) {

            if ( max < arr[N-1-i] - arr[j])
                max = arr[N-1-i] - arr[j];
        }

    }


    cout << max << endl;
    delete [] arr;

    return 0;

}
```

**EDIT:** I tried to take a jab at Peter de Rivaz's approach on getting a  linear complexity. I noticed that there were repeated calculations in my code. So I decided to go about it this way: since endpoints are all that matter, I changed the outer loop so that every time it iterates, I would be shifting an "interval" (shorter by one element) through the original array.

For k = 1: an array of length N - 1 (2 fitting positions in the original)
For k = 2: an array of length N - 2 (3 fitting..)

and so on. Surprisingly, even though there are no excessive operations, the time limit is still exceeded.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main() {

    int N, K;
    int *arr;
    int max;

    cin >> N;

    arr = new int[N];

    if (N < 2 || N > 500000) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Los input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cin >> K;


    if (K < 0 || K > N - 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Los input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < -1000000 || arr[i] > 1000000) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Los input\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }   
    }

    max = arr[N-1] - arr[0];

    for (int i = 1; i <= K; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {

            if (max < arr[j+N-1-i] - arr[j]) 
                max = arr[j + N - 1 - i] - arr[j];

            cout << (arr[j + N - 1 - i] - arr[j]) << endl;

        }   

    }   
    cout << max << endl;
    delete [] arr;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @Ron It means the contest is looking for an algorith that's better than O(n^2).

Comment: Brute force solutions almost never meet the time requirements of these programming challenges. If you have a working solution (other than it being too slow) you can try asking for help improving your solution over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help . Note that I have linked you to their help page. Definitely read the help pages before asking.

Comment: The whole point of this challenge is for you to figure out a more clever algorithm than trying every combination. You already figured out that you only need the endpoints of the range, but you need to simplify it further.

Comment: One thing you might consider: the order of the array elements doesn't matter, so maybe you can improve things by sorting the array.

Comment: Actually, it does, you can't arrange them how you'd like. In colloquial terms, the question is, 'which numbers are best to pluck out?'

Answer (score 1):

If you consider a particular value for lastNumber (by removing x from the right end of the array), then we will get the biggest total by choosing the smallest possible value for firstNumber.

We have removed x, so we can remove up to K-x more from the left.  Therefore the best value for this value of x comes from the smallest value in the first K-x+1 entries (these are all the possible values for firstNumber).

Start with x equal to K and work in decreasing order.

Decreasing order is useful because the minimum of the first K-x+1 entries can be computed with O(1) extra work from the previous minimum.

Overall, this results in O(n) complexity.